# access data from a state with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'll try to keep this as simple as possible without losing the context of the question.

Suppose I have a state using ui-router

```
$stateProvider.state("home", {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "...",
    meta: {
        label: "...",
        ...
    }
});
```

How can I access the properties and values of the `meta` object of the current state so that I can apply those in a view, for example:

```
<section class="content-header">
    <h1>
        {{meta.label}}
    </h1>
</section>
```

So the example above would display the value of `label` from the `meta` object of the current state.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects

Answer (score 0):

Following the [ui-router doc](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki), you should be able to access it by injecting $state and using this:

```
$state.current.meta.label
```